# Using Pandas to sample DataFrame using a specific column's weight

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a DataFrame which look like:

```
  index  name   city
  0      Yam    Hadera
  1      Meow   Hadera
  2      Don    Hadera
  3      Jazz   Hadera
  4      Bond   Tel Aviv
  5      James  Tel Aviv
```

I want Pandas to randomly choose values, using the number of appearances in the `city` column (kind of using: `df.city.value_counts()`), so the results of my magic function, suppose:

```
df.magic_sample(3, weight_column='city')
```

might look like:

```
  0     Yam      Hadera
  1     Meow     Hadera
  2     Bond     Tel Aviv
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can group by `city` and then sample each group based on their length compared to the length of the original data frame:

```
df.groupby('city', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.sample(3 * len(g)/len(df)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Eventually, for larger data sets, it selects fewer than `N` values in the overall (in your example, N=3). Is there a way to do it so that I'll get exactly N values in total?

Comment: @Infinity What would happen if you had 10 groups with 2 rows each and N=3?

Comment: As @TedPetrou commented, this sampling method may not always work since you can only sample integer number of rows from a group, but the *weight * total number of rows* can be fractional.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, maybe you are looking for `random.sample`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from random import sample
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('Yam', 'Hadera'), ('Meow', 'Hadera'), ('Don', 'Hadera'), ('Jazz', 'Hadera'), ('Bond', 'Tel Aviv'), ('James', 'Tel Aviv')], columns=('name', 'city'))
>>> df
    name      city
0    Yam    Hadera
1   Meow    Hadera
2    Don    Hadera
3   Jazz    Hadera
4   Bond  Tel Aviv
5  James  Tel Aviv
>>> df.iloc[sample(range(len(df)), 3), :]
   name      city
4  Bond  Tel Aviv
0   Yam    Hadera
1  Meow    Hadera
```